# How can I redirect user to a link I get after form data was sent?

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm struggling with php file to gather and send landing page form details.

The main problem is to redirect user to the link which server generates and shows up in API response.

**cURL example:**

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/integration/v1/auth/register",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\n\"firstName\": \"Mike\", \n\"lastName\": \"Tyson\", \n\"phone\": \"12345678\",\n\"email\": \"testtessttsets@mailnator.com\", \n\"password\": \"string12345\", \n\"ip\": \"31.43.62.154\", \n\"affId\": 40134, \n\"cxdToken\": \"\", \n\"brandId\": \"\", \n\"userAgent\": \"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1\", \n\"langId\": \"PL\", \n\"countryOfRegistration\": \"PL\", \n\"landingPage\": \"https://lp.handelpro.com\",\n\"redirectedFromUrl\": \"https://lp.handelpro.com/aff-mt5-main\", \n\"countryByIp\": \"PL\", \n\"processId\": \"202010-16T0906:33.185\", \n\"secretKey\": \"\"\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Cookie: __cfduid=dc9f984d5321eea8132bfcf4ed378236a1616175186"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

**Server response:**

```
"token": "26B1836A70D9ABF4A4B48F38C8F6ED4A8C85633121A720BF65B7CA6EAC24DBE3112BC843D5F9B69AE8FF38BA9CB1724DB7525EA62852FBC5A3194509CBEAF5AC",
"redirectUrl": "https://example.com/lpLogin/26B1836A70D9ABF4A4B48F38C8F6ED4A8C85633121A720BF65B7CA6EAC24DBE3112BC843D5F9B69AE8FF38BA9CB1724DB7525EA62852FBC5A3194509CBEAF5AC?lang=PL",
"status": 0
```

Basically, I need to redirect user to that "redirectUrl" after clicking on "submit" at Landing page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `echo $response` and add this instead.

```
$url = json_decode($response)->redirectUrl;

header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try that one and reply here